# editing the default section and making an array of buttons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, netbeans

As I drag and drop a button in netbeans,code generator generates the code like :

```
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
```

What if I want an array of these buttons ? How do I edit this in netbeans ?

Like :

```
private javax.swing.JButton buttonArray[] = new JButton[3];
```

*Note: I am using netbeans 7.3*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
JButton[] buttonArray = {jButton1, jButton2, jButton3};
```

would work.

But having said that, you are likely far better off at this stage not to use NetBeans generated code at all and instead code your Swing applications by hand. The NetBeans code generator can save you time if you understand Swing well, but if you're new to Swing and to Java, while it can help you create easy simply GUI's, it can become an impossible bear if you want to stretch the envelope even a little bit.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: and to you too, 1+

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the form editor, I'm pretty sure you can't, however.

What you can do is create one yourself...

```
public class MyAwesomeClass extends ... {
    private JButton[] arrayOfButtons = new JButton[] {
        jButton1, jButton2, jButton3
    };
    // Remainder of class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a form normally, then close the netbeans and open an external text editor, such as gedit (if you're using linux) and remove the following lines:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
```

and

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify
// End of variables declaration
```

That done, save the file and open netbeans again and then you can freely edit these sessions.
When you finish editing the code in netbeans, edit the file again and put the lines in the file again.